# SESSIONID is not available in the HTTPServletRequest object when the SameSite is enabled in chrome://flags

Tags: java, jsp, web-development-server

We have a site, and we are loading it in a div tag in a standard JSP.
We have to set the samesite attribute to none and secure it to the HTTPServletRequest object.
The issue we are facing is when the #Same-Site cookies are enabled in the chrome browser `chrome://flags`
The JSESSIONID is not available in the HTTPServletRequest object, and thus we are not able to set the SameSite attribute in the HTTPResponse object.

When the SameSite attribute is disabled in the chrome://flags, the JSESSIONID is available.

Thus, we face this session expiry issue only after #same-site-by-default-cookies and #cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure is enabled(chrome default setting previously it was disabled). We need a suggestion to fix this issue. Please help

Comment: Are you aware of CORS? Did you try using this technique?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of CORS and we have enabled the traffic so that CORS is not blocking the traffic..